# Logical breakpiont

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug

Using Xdebug (with or without PhpStorm) how can I define a breakpoint using a logical condition instead of specifying location of breakpoint by line number. e.g. execution is needed to be stopped when `$x==3` or `is_null($y)'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You can make a breakpoint conditional, as in "stop at line 123 only if `$x==3`" or "stop if an exception is thrown but only if `$x==3`," but you can't make a breakpoint *purely* conditional.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know phpstorm, but with other debugger clients you could use xdebug_break() to stop the execution. just put the following snippet into your code somewhere where you $x and $y using.

```
if ($x==3 || is_null($y)) {
  xdebug_break();
}
```

see the xdebug [documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions)

> bool xdebug_break() Emits a breakpoint to the debug client.
>
> This function makes the debugger break on the specific line as if a
>   normal file/line breakpoint was set on this line.

Comment: That's not really what OP has asked for. He wants "global breakpoint" -- execution should be stopped when certain condition is meant without associating it with any particular line of code. Your solution is the same as conditional breakpoint .. but that one is better as requires no code modification (everything done on IDE/editor side).